# How to dissect/parse 'price elasticity of demand'?

Tags: grammaticality

Source: p 90-91, *Principles of Microeconomics*, 7 Ed, 2014, by N Gregory Mankiw

> [p 90:] **[1.] price elasticity of demand** = 
>   a measure of how much
>   the quantity demanded
>   of a good responds to a
>   change in the price of
>   that good, computed as
>   the percentage change
>   in quantity demanded
>   divided by the percentage
>   change in price
>
> [p 91:] Price elasticity of demand =
>   Percentage change in quantity demanded / 
>   Percentage change in price

If I rephrased the definition above (to the right of the equal sign), I'd formulate it as: 2. elasticity of demand `in response to price`. So why does **price** precede **elasticity of demand**?
If 2 is right, then did 1 adjectivise or nominialise `in response to price` as just: **price**?

Comment: It's just a suboptimal choice by people who focus on numbers not language. Elasticity of demand in response to changes in price.  Price-related/price-dependent elasticity of demand.  Price elasticity of demand.  They just forget the "related/dependent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The economists need easily said, and easily understood, terms that combine some of the following concepts:

- Price
- Volume (called Quantity in the original post)
- Supply
- Demand
- Elasticity
- Income
- Capital

In a typical microeconomics lecture, a phrase like "price elasticity" or "elasticity of supply" or "elasticity of demand" might be said several times.  Thus, economists have good reason to use short, well-defined phrases instead of long phrases.

In your particular example, the economist is defining a phrase that combines the concepts of price, elasticity, and demand.  "Price elasticity of demand" can be shortened to "Price elasticity" (when it is clear that demand is being discussed) or "elasticity of demand" (because elasticities default to price elasticities unless stated otherwise).

Your interpretation is correct:  "in response to price" is being turned into an adjective.  In English, adjectives are usually one word, before the noun they modify.  Adjectivalization (say that three times fast!) thus shortens a five syllable phrase to one syllable.  Using price as the default variable can shorten the phrase to zero syllables.

As you learn more about economics, you will learn about concepts like:

- Price elasticity of supply
- Income elasticity of demand
- How supply depends upon the capital stock
- How supply depends upon the value of labor that is utilized
- Production possibility frontiers, which are commonly approximated using functions that make it easy to calculate elasticities of supply (with respect to price, capital stock, and labor usage).

By the way, these concepts rarely do a good job of modelling the effects of new products, new tools, and new ideas.  Thus, macroeconomics can only model about half of the long-term economic growth seen in countries like the United States.

Comment: This isn't unique to econ: nuclear engineering has "void coefficient of reactivity" and "power coefficient..." and "fuel temperature coefficient..." The basic structure is the same: "A B of C" describes how C behaves as a function of A (this is often seen when B is "coefficient")

Comment: +1. Thank you for your advice on economics, in supplement to your supernal answer on the linguistics! I always appreciate enlightenment on 'the big picture' or 'grand perspective'.